# Password protect resque-web

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque, php-resque

I'm running `php-resque` with PHP and have installed `resque-web` to use the admin interface.

**Problem:** How do you password protect the `resque-web` pages? I am not familiar with Ruby/Rails/Sinatra so a solution that does not require much knowledge of them will be perfect!

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way to protect a webpage or directory with a password is a .htaccess/.htpasswd file.

To create those files, you could use a online generator like [this](http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/password/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Resque::Auth::Basic` -- just specify something like this in your config.ru:

```
map "/resque" do
  use Rack::Auth::Basic do |username, password|
    [username, password] == ['admin', 'admin']
    end
  run Resque::Server.new
end
```

### NOTE :

`/resque` is the path where I wanted to mount resque-web but you can choose your own.

There are also other ways to do it but this is the basic approach.

Hope this

**EDIT**

Oh, you mean you don't have a Sinatra application at all? Well. that would be pain. Then there are 2 approaches you can use:

a) define a config.ru file and write the code above in it and do this: `rackup config.ru -p 3001` and redirect(proxy-pass) the `/resque` via web-server to that URL

b) I recommend you apply your BASIC AUTH ON web-server itself (I know nginx has it check [this](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpAuthBasicModule) sure Apache or Lighthttpd would also have the same)

I hope now it makes sense.

Comment: This is a really basic question: Where can I find `config.ru`? I assume its in the base directory of `resque`, but I installed `resque` using `gem install resque` so how do I find `config.ru`? I'm running PHP for most of the site and have almost no knowledge of Ruby/Rails.